# angular2 relationship between @Component and Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular

How is the relationship between a component controller class and the component is formed. Is it simply based on the positioning that whatever class comes after a given component, it becomes the component controller class for the component defined before it. How does it works if you have multiple components in a single js file. How do you associate a class anywhere in the js file to a component.

Along the same lines, is there such a thing as child components and in that case do these child components inherit something from parent components and more specifically from the component controller class of parent component.

Comment: after going through some additional material my question sort of seems stupid. Component and Template are annotations so yeah they are applied on a class which is how that class is linked with Component. As for child components that makes sense too because any related components are included in the root component as directives

Comment: I don't think it is a stupid question. I just could not see it for a while until I saw it. It just does not look as natural as in Java - even if imports are added and it appears above the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is the relationship between a component controller class and the component is formed. Is it simply based on the positioning that whatever class comes after a given component, it becomes the component controller class for the component defined before it.

Yes.

> How does it works if you have multiple components in a single js file

Have the structure:

```
@Component ...
class Foo ...

@Component ...
class Bar ...
```

> Is there such a thing as child components and in that case do these child components inherit something from parent components and more specifically from the component controller class of parent component.

Components don't inherit. Components *compose*. Search *inheritance vs. composition* (but I sure you know this).

Also see : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2249

Answer (score 0):

There are some kind of parents which are declared in the class constructor. Here is an example http://victorsavkin.com/post/118372404541/the-core-concepts-of-angular-2:

```
class Component {
    constructor(sibling:SiblingCmp,
          @Parent parent:ParentCmp,
          @Ancestor ancestor:AncestorCmp) {
    }
}
```